# Save a raw html form django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to save some user data from a raw html form in django.
My code looks like this:

```
# This is the view -->
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    age = request.POST['age']
    password = request.POST['password']

    # Some validation (But unnecessary for this Question)
    # save the form into my user model
```

So the real question is: How do i save name, email, age and password to my database?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to follow [Django's official documentation - model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have an model an model Form :

```
if request.method =="POST":
    form=Form(request.POST) # you need to init form in previous view
    if form.is_valid():
        #inserte your actions here 
        form.save()
```